# Is there a way to add "active" class to list item based on its location in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a fixed height div with a list of clickable list items. In the middle of the div, I have an absolute positioned line that is meant to signify a selected item. Right now, it's just a static line.

Is there a way to add an active class to the list item as it is "selected" by the line?

http://dev.chrislamdesign.com/shortwave/

Comment: You could either treat the item in the middle of the visible list as the selected one, or use `getBoundingClientRect` to determine which element intersects with the indicator line.

Comment: @IronMan - Awesome! Thanks. Do you have a resource on how to make this happen, or could you show me a quick example? I'm new to JS and don't have a good sense on what it can/can't do and how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` method. Something like this:

```
let lineCoords, lineTop, lineCenter;

// try to remove these two lines, leave just the scroll event listener
// document.getElementById('scrollUp1').addEventListener('click', setActive);
// document.getElementById('scrollDown1').addEventListener('click', setActive);

// 2nd edition: added these event listeners
window.addEventListener('scroll', getLineCoords);
window.addEventListener('load', getLineCoords);

// added this line
document.getElementById('wrap-scroll-1').addEventListener('scroll', setActive);

function setActive() {
    const li = document.elementFromPoint(lineCenter, lineTop + lineCoords.height);
    clearActive();
    li.classList.add('active');
}

function clearActive() {
    const ul = document.getElementById('ul-scroll-1');
    const activeLi = ul.querySelector('li.active');

    if (activeLi) {
        activeLi.classList.remove('active');
    }
}

// 2nd edition: added this function
function getLineCoords() {
    lineCoords = document.querySelector('.orange-line').getBoundingClientRect();
    lineTop = lineCoords.top;
    lineCenter = lineCoords.left + (lineCoords.width / 2);
}
```

You can see this in action here: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/wiyohazici/1/edit?html,css,js,output). These `up` and `down` buttons are assumed to scroll the list, but I don't have this functionality, because that's not a point here - just scroll it youself. The point here is that the element under the orange line will get `active` class each time you click one of these buttons.
So, take this code and edit it as you want.

**Edited:** I added an scroll event listener to the `#wrap-scroll-1` container, because I guess the scroll event occurs right on it. If not - you can change it. Look at this in action: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/vuvoxikive/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

**2nd edition:** Added event listeners to reassign the orange line coordinates every time when the page scrolled, and also when the page is loaded. Take a look at the result here: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/gugitibodu/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! This partially worked as well. The active class is getting set only when you click the scrollUp1 and scrollDown1 buttons, but now when you simply scroll using a mousewheel. Is there a way to set it using both the buttons and mousewheel scroll? Thank you so much again!

Comment: I edited the code. I added a line, and I also removed one - 5th line `const li = document.elementFromPoint(lineCenter, lineTop + lineCoords.height);` - we actually don't need it there, because we have it in `setActive` function.

Comment: And, actually, if you have `scroll` event listener, then, I suppose, you can remove buttons `click` event listeners. Because when you click on them, the `scroll` event will occur automatically (I guess, again, because I can't try it :))

Comment: Great! I'm happy to help you :)

Comment: Hi again, Chris. I found a bug in my solution. Everything works ok until you scroll the page. When you scroll it, the position of the orange line changes, but because of we get its position only one time, after page scrolled we will get wrong result. So. I added a function to get the line's coord every time when the page scrolls and also when it loads. Look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Andrew! I implemented this and it is working. HOwever, it oddly spits out a console error regarding the height: 

```(index):597 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.setActive ((index):597)```

Perhaps this is due to the height being set as the last function?

Comment: Yes, I see... This error shouldn't occur because of `lineCoords` assigned in the last function, for we use `load` event handler, which assigns `lineCoords` as soon as the page has loaded. So, I really can't understand clearly why this is happening, but I suppose that this is because you wrapped this code in `jQuery()` function. This code works without jQuery library, so you don't need to wrap it in it. This code has `load` event handler, which supposed to be loaded firstly, but because of being wrapped in jQuery function, `load` event handler fires only after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: So, try to take this code out of the jQeury function. Just `<script>..and javascript code right here..</script>` And note, that all `<script>` tags shouldn't be inside of other `<div>`s. They should go right after the last `<div>` on the page.

Comment: Hmm...when i take it out of the jquery function, i get this error: ```(index):571 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'lineCoords' has already been declared```

Comment: I mean, you accidentally put this code twice, or even trice (sorry for my English :))

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I've got 3 different lists to run this on, should i simply rename variables to duplicate the function?

Comment: Of course names of variables shouldn't repeat. Only one variable with one name. The simplest solution is to rename all variables for the first list `lineCoords1`, `lineTop1`... for the second list `lineCoords2`, `lineTop2`... and so on. And rename all functions names too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andrew! And sorry about all the quesitons. I tried renaming variables and am getting this console error now: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```. It's pointing to ```document.getElementById('wrap-scroll-1').addEventListener('scroll', setActive);
``` but I clearly have that ID in my document.

Comment: Ok, I told you that that was the simplest solution... But, I guess I was wrong :) The simplest is this: [https://jsbin.com/voladan/2/edit?js]. I wrapped the code in `(function() {...code here...})()`. This is the way to hide your variables from the outside world. Just the code inside this `(function(){...})();` knows about the variables which are in it. But the outside world doesn't know about them at all. So, in this case we shouldn't have this variable names conflict. This example doesn't work on my HTML there, but in yours it should work good.

Comment: Thanks, again, Andrew. No Console Errors but it is not assigned the class at all anymore. :( Any suggestions?

Comment: So strange, when I wrap it in a jquery function, it works perfectly in Chrome but in any other browser.

Comment: Hm.. It's really strange. Now I see a lot of errors in the console, but class assignment is working though... I can't really understand what's wrong here, but I suppose that this is because of some scripts, that run before this code... Anyway, if it's alright for you how it works now, then you can just hide the console messages :) If so, I will show you the way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not getting any console errors in Chrome at all, but it does not work in Firefox or IE at all. :(

Comment: Ok, one reason why it's not working in IE (and maybe in Firefox) is that it doesn't understand `let` and `const` keywords. So, try to just replace them on `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the rects of the line and each option to find which is selected:

```
const line = document.querySelector('#emotional .orange-line');
const options = document.querySelector('#emotional .selection-options').children;

const lineY = line.getBoundingClientRect().y;

const optionAfterSelected = [...options].find((option) => {
  return option.getBoundingClientRect().y > lineY;
});

const selected = optionAfterSelected.previousSibling;
selected.classList.add('selected');
```

The selected option is the one with the largest `y` value without exceeding the `y` value of the orange line. To make things simple, the loop just returns the first option with a `y` value greater than the line, then grabs its previous sibling.

#### Update

To get this code to run whenever the user scrolls, you can wrap it in a function and attach it as an eventListener:

```
function updateSelection(menuId) {
  const line = document.querySelector(menuId + ' .orange-line');
  const options = document.querySelector(menuId + ' .selection-options').children;

  const lineY = line.getBoundingClientRect().y;

  const optionAfterSelected = [...options].find((option) => {
    return option.getBoundingClientRect().y > lineY;
  });

  const selected = optionAfterSelected.previousSibling;
  selected.classList.add('selected');
}

document.querySelector('#emotional .wrap-container').addEventListener('wheel', () => {
  updateSelection('#emotional');
});

document.querySelector('#genre .wrap-container').addEventListener('wheel', () => {
  updateSelection('#genre');
});

document.querySelector('#cinematic .wrap-container').addEventListener('wheel', () => {
  updateSelection('#cinematic');
});
```

Comment: That worked! The only issue is, it is only assigning the class of selected one time on document load. Is there a way to assign this in real-time as the user scrolls? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: @chris updated my answer to show how you can update the selection on scroll. Once the logic is wrapped in a function like this, you can call it any time selection needs to be updated- on scroll, on mouse click, on button click, etc.